# Can the contracts in the Solidity repository be used in production?

Tags: solidity

In the [solidity repository](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/tree/develop/std) there are some standard contracts:

- owned
- mortal
- token
- StandardToken

they are all imported in a file `std.sol`

I was wondering if these contracts could be used in solidity and if yes how?

The contracts are on my hard disk as I have `solc` but providing the full path to import them seems awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but you can simply put them in the same folder, or, simply copy and paste them into the .sol contract. I've seen both. Once it's deployed, it's immutable code, so it really doesn't matter, and, in effect this is what the compiler does anyway.

Comment: it was not explicitly stated but I wanted to reference the contracts without copying them

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could, I wouldn't use them in production.
There are extremely outdated, use a very early compiler version and, thus, are potentially vulnerable.